# Trouble print meta tags with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a meta tag in my view based on data in my model...my view code looks like this:

```
<meta name="description" content="<%=Html.Encode(Model.MetaDescription) %>" />
```

But my output looks like this:

```
meta name="description" content="&lt;%=Html.Encode(Model.MetaDescription) %>" />
```

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably adding this `meta` tag to a `<head>` tag which is marked at `runat="server"`. Try:

```
<meta name="description" content='<%=Html.Encode(Model.MetaDescription) %>' />
```

I don't have a clear idea about what the actual problem is, as I don't have the full source, but to workaround:

```
<meta name="description" content=<%= "\"" + Html.Encode(Model.MetaDescription) + "\"" %> />
```

Comment: Tried that...no change.  If I strip the single or double quotes out it will work...so in the end it looks like:

 content=this is my content

but that's probably a bad idea.

Comment: Is my assumption correct? Are you using <head runat="server">?

Comment: Yep, I was gonna suggest dropping head runat=server if you don't have a need.

Comment: I stripped it out and it worked...kind of wondering why by default a view has runat in the head tag anyway...oh well.

Comment: For example, it's required for setting the Title at the <%@ Page %> directive. I don't like it, by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

Mehrdad's second solution works fine and renders a valid XHTML, but causes VS IDE to complain about the invalid syntax (it doesn't "see" the double quotes at design-time and thinks they are missing).

A better (working) syntax would be:

```
<meta name="description" content=<%= "" + Html.Encode(Model.MetaDescription) %> />
```

It seems like a bug in the MVC rendering engine, and the empty string in the beginning is a workaround...