# Why I can't resolve client url for css files?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is my asp code:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
<head runat="server">
    <title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
    </title>
    <link href='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/Content/Site.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.js")%>' type="text/javascript" />
    <script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")%>' type="text/javascript" />
    <link href='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/Content/redmond/jquery-ui.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="ui-theme" />
</head>
```

And here it's the html rendered:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
<head>
    <title>Espace de travail</title>
    <link href="&lt;%: ResolveClientUrl(&quot;~/Content/Site.css&quot;) %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src='Scripts/jquery.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='Scripts/jquery-ui.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="&lt;%: ResolveClientUrl(&quot;~/Content/redmond/jquery-ui.css&quot;) %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="ui-theme" />
</head>
```

Why asp can resolve url for my .js script file but not for my css file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The URL returned by this method is relative to the folder containing the source file in which the control is instantiated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx).

Use `ResolveUrl` or `Url.Content` helper method instead. The first link got encoded because of `runat="server"` attribute on `head` tag. Consider removing attribute or try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873880/trouble-print-meta-tags-with-asp-net-mvc).

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I used to get around the link tag issue:

```
<%= "<link href=\"" + ResolveClientUrl( "~/Content/Site.css") + "\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />" %>
```

Note how I put the entire link tag within an embedded code block.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `runat="server"` on your `<link>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<%=` instead of `<%:`.

Answer (score 0):

<%: automatically encodes the result string while <%= will display the exact text. If you use your original example and put <%= it will work.

Comment: Nop it doesn't works with <%=, the good solution is: Url.Content()